# power transformation with negative values?

Tags: data-transformation, data-preprocessing

Is there a name for this type of transformation:

\begin{equation}
sgn(x) * |x|^p
\end{equation}
where $p$ is an arbitrary number (e.g., 1/2 and 1/3 for square and cube roots, respectively) and $sgn$ is the signum function?

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/233616/1021) something similar is suggested for a transformation using an arbitrary  $p$.

Are these valid transformation prior to regression etc. (to bring  heavy-tailed distributions closer to normal)? They seem to offer less "compression" over a wide range of numbers than the inverse hyperbolic sine does (which is often recommended for data sets with negative values).

Comment: It is natural, and tempting, to try something like this with data that are differences of skewed data.  It rarely works (and has extremely poor properties for negative $p.$)  If this question was motivated by your analysis of a dataset, why not ask directly about the original issue?

Comment: I don't think it can even be discussed usefully unless $p > 0$. The case of the cube root seems the commonest application, which I have found helpful for visualization and analysis of glacier terminus change  e.g. _Nature_ 500, 563–566 (2013).and profile and plan curvature in geomorphometry.

Comment: @whuber when you say it rarely "works"/has poor properties, what type of properties do you speak of? If these transformations make the data more normal to conform to e.g., regression methods, are there more that we should consider? And yes I did not consider the $p<0$ case but for $p>0$ it could be fine?

Comment: The poorest property is that it is discontinuous and unbounded at the origin for non-positive $p.$  Regression methods rarely require Normality: one seeks approximate *symmetry* of distribution.  Often, data that span zero have been computed as differences and in those cases, if it's possible, transforming the data before subtracting them is more effective and more readily interpretable.

Comment: @whuber In analytical chemistry, instrument noise and sample handling leads to some perturbation to the data and results in negative values while the majority of points or positive. Often lognormal distributions are good approximations except near zero... Actually you're right about the symmetry of the distribution.

Comment: Often, a good model for that situation is a lognormal distribution of true concentrations plus Normal errors.  Again, attempting to transform the data in some *ad hoc* way is usually neither effective nor insightful, because it is trying to cope with the effects of both phenomena simultaneously.

Comment: @whuber Yes lognormal is a good approximation, except near zero. I believe Wayne Ott proposed a 3-parameter lognormal distribution ("LN3C") to handle exactly such data sets but was not widely adopted. As for normal errors, that is true, but the variance scales with concentration - and concentrations spanning orders of magnitude - the errors end up becoming visibly heteroscedastic. Weighted least squares methods are therefore popular but requires precise knowledge of the errors ($1/x^2$ doesn't work since concentrations can be zero). So indeed I'd hoped a transformation could do the trick.